# How to show results of a jquery POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to build a webchat from scratch using jQuery. I can now successfully send messages to my (also self built) API, and I now want to poll for new messages. I do this using the function below. The problem is that I can't seem to do anything with the json which is returned. I tried `JSON.parse()` and `jQuery.parseJSON()`, but none of them seem to work. There is simply no alert popping up at all. When I use a simple `alert("with a simple string here");` it does work, so it does reach the success point.

```
function updateConversation(){
    if(!instance) {
        instance = true;
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/api/support/" + "1",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'action': 'GET_MESSAGES',
                    'user_id': user_id,
                    'last_message_id':last_message_id
                }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var usingjsonparse = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert(usingjsonparse.messages);
                    var usingjqueryparse = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    alert(usingjsonparse.messages);
                    if (data.text) {
                        for (var i=0; i< data.text.length; i++) {
                            $('#conversation').append($("<P>"+ data.text[i]));
                        }
                    }
                    document.getElementById('conversation').scrollTop = document.getElementById('conversation').scrollHeight;
                    instance = false;
                    // last_message_id = data.id;

                }
            });
    } else {
        setTimeout(updateConversation, 1000);
    }
}
```

The json I expect is this:

```
{"messages": [{"is_supporter": True, "text": u"aergaerg", "id": 1, "created": "1391609527"}, {"is_supporter": True, "text": u"eargaerg", "id": 2, "created": "1391609551"}, etc.]}
```

Does anybody know how I can view the raw string of data that is being returned? I tried `data`, `data.messages`, `data.messages[0]`, and a zillion other variations, but to no avail. When I `alert(typeof(data));` I get `object`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

ps. does anybody know a more simple way of seeing whats going on, instead of always alerting everything?

Comment: `data.responseText`. Save yourself a world of pain and glitches and build this in Meteor.js.

Comment: As you're passing `dataType: 'json'` to the function, the response is already parsed. Have you tried looking at the `data` object in developer tools?

Comment: The response you are returning is already parsed as json because you set the `dataType:json` you should do a `console.log(data)` to see what you are currently returning

Comment: Agree with @BradM -- check into a templating engine, makes life easier :)

Comment: @Phylogenesis - I first thought that as well, so I tried `alert(data.messages);`, and the same for `data.messages[0]` and `data.messages[0].text`. But none of this returns anything resembling what I'm looking for..

Comment: @kramer65 Use your browser's web development tools. Use a breakpoint inside the success function and look at what's returned. This will give a clearer idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

You have:

```
dataType: "json"
```

This tells jQuery to ignore what the server says the response is and treat it as JSON. It will parse it and convert it to an object.

Then you have:

```
var usingjsonparse = JSON.parse(data);
```

Which will convert the object to a string (such as `"[Object object]"`) and try to parse that as JSON, which it isn't.

What you should be doing is having the server return the appropriate content type (`application/json`), not mention `JSON.parser` and not mention `dataType`.

---

Problem 2:

```
{'messages': [{'is
```

… is not JSON. JSON strings must be delimited by `"` characters. You have some other errors there too. It looks like a stringified Python object. Push it through a JSON serialiser before sending it to the browser.

---

> Does anybody know how I can view the raw string of data that is being returned?

The raw string will be visible through your browser's developer tools in the Net tab.

You can see what gets passed into the function by `console.log(data)`.

Comment: About problem 2: excuse me, I copied the "json" from within python before it is jsonified. I'll change that right now.